# Search for items in a Map

Tags: scala, dictionary

I am new to scala, my objective is to iterate over list and check if items in the list exist the map as its keys and if they exist return the value for that key.

I did the following:

```
  def getMatchingValues(listItmes: List[String]) = {
    for (item <- listItems) {
      theMap.keys.foreach { i =>
        if (i.equals(item)) {
          theMap(i)
        }
        "NoMatch"
      }
    }
  }
```

I am trying to figure if there is a better way to do this in scala?

Comment: This implementation will return `Unit` because you used `foreach`. What type of data structure did you want?

Comment: May be a list, in addition if I get a list will I be able flatten the list to a string?

Answer (score 4):

Map has a `getOrElse` method which does what you want:

```
def getMatchingValues(listItems: List[String]) = listItems map (theMap.getOrElse(_,"NoMatch"))
```

At least I think that is what you want.  Here's an example:

```
scala> val theMap = Map("a"->"A", "b" -> "B")
theMap: scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,String] = Map(a -> A, b -> B)

scala> val listItems = List("a","b","c")
listItems: List[String] = List(a, b, c)

scala> listItems map (theMap.getOrElse(_,"NoMatch"))
res0: List[String] = List(A, B, NoMatch)
```

Comment: This is great but the problem is I loose the notion of which key had which item. Or did I get it wrong?

Comment: what would you want the output to be for my example with `List("a","b","c")` ?  `List(("a", "A"), ("b","B"), ("c", "NoMatch"))` perhaps?

Answer (score 2):

A possible solution with flatMap:

```
/* Return Some[String] if found, None if not found, then flatten */
def getMatchingValues(listItems: List[String], theMap: Map[String, String]): List[String] =
    listItems.flatMap(item => theMap.get(item))

/* Same thing with some syntactic sugar */
def getMatchingValuesSmartass(listItems: List[String], theMap: Map[String, String]): List[String] = 
    listItems flatMap theMap.get

val l = List("1", "3", "5", "7")
val m = Map("5" -> "five", "2" -> "two", "1" -> "one")

getMatchingValues(l, m)
getMatchingValuesSmartass(l, m)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the map.get method and handle the result with pattern matching

```
list.map { x => map.get(x) match {
  case None => "No match"
  case Some(i) => (x, i)
}}
```

The above code returns a list of pairs where each pair represents the elements of the list and the value associated in the map ("No match" if not found)

Answer (score 1):

If I was you, I would do two steps. Given this `Map`:

```
val map = Map("a" -> "b", "b" -> "c", "c" -> "d", "d" -> "e")
```

and this `List`:

```
val list = List("a", "c", "e")
```

At first I would `map` an `Option` value to every item in the `List`. Giving you if there is a value for the item.

```
val mapped = list.map(item => item -> map.get(item))
```

This will give you this:

```
mapped: List[(String, Option[String])] = 
    List(("a",Some("b")), ("c",Some("d")), ("e", None))
```

Calling `get` on the map returns a wrapped result. If there is a result, you will get the result wrapped in a `Some`. Otherwise you will get a `None`. Both are subclasses of `Option` `Option` is a closure-construct, that provides you a null-value without having to deal with `null`. Now you are able to `map` again, to reach your goal.

```
val result = mapped.map(tuple => tuple._1 -> tuple._2.getOrElse("No match"))
result: List[(String, String)] = List(("a","b"), ("c","d"), ("e","No match"))
```

`getOrElse` extracts the value of a `Some` or falls back to the parameter if it is a `None`.

 To make it look more professional, we can write this expression in one line ;)

```
val result = list.map(item => item -> map.get(item).getOrElse("No match"))
```

This will give you the exact same result.